# Debug with mvc 3 source code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, debugging, razor

i've downloaded the mvc3 source code and am trying to add it to an existing project so i can debug. I get the following compile error - The referenced assembly System.Web.WebPages.dll was not found. If this assembly is produced by another one of your projects, please make sure to build that project before building this one.   Do these dlls not come with the source code?

Comment: What kind of project do you have created? There is a missing reference I think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `mvc3-rtm-sources.zip` you have downloaded there are 2 folders:

- mvc3
- webpages

It is the `webpages` folder that contains the WebMatrix stuff (System.Web.Helpers, System.Web.Razor, System.Web.WebPages, ...). So make sure you have compiled those projects first.